# difference between find and find_by when modifying a record in-memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Say I have these two classes

```
class Gadget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widgets
end

class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gadget
  # table has string attribute .color
end
```

And let's say that the database contains one gadget and one widget, each with `id = 1`, and the widget has a color of `nil`.

Modifying a record retrieved with `.find`

```
g = Gadget.first
w = g.widgets.find { |widg| widg.id == 1 }
w.color = "blue"
g.widgets.first.color
=> "blue"
```

Modifying a record retrieved with `.find_by`

```
g = Gadget.first
w = g.widgets.find_by(id: 1)
w.color = "blue"
g.widgets.first.color
=> nil
```

I can't account for this difference.

Comment: any chance more than one widget with id = 1?

Comment: Assume that id is unique.

Comment: Sure that g.widgets.first is the same id in both cases?

Comment: We can even say that the gadget has exactly one widget.

Comment: fascinating behavior

Answer (score 0):

If you use `find_by` method, rails add that find_by statement to the end of the query so there will be only one record loaded to the memory (if there is) and the DB is here to find that record. If you use `find` method with a block, rails will first load all the widgets to the memory then it will search for a specific one for the given statement which will cause extra memory usage since DB can do the same job. Also if you use the `find` method like this: `g.widgets.find(1)` this will do same as the `g.widgets.find_by(id: 1)` method.